# Two strange bytes at the beginning of each message of a Kafka message produced by my Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I develop a Kafka connector which simply creates messages for each line in a file retrieved from an external API. It works nicely but now I try to consume the messages and I have two strange bytes at the beginning of each value. I can reproduce the problem with the console consumer and with my kafka stream processor.

```
�168410002,OpenX Market,459980962,OpenX_Bidder_Order_merkur_bidder_800x250,313115722,OpenX_Bidder_ANY_LI_merkur_800x250_550,106800839362,OpenX_Bidder_Creative_merkur_800x250_2,10
```

The source files are good and even printlns before creating the SourceRecord don't show these two bytes. I used a struct with one field before and now use a simple String schema but I still have the same problem:

```
def convert(line: String, ...) = {
...
val record = new SourceRecord(
  Partition.sole(partition),
  offset.forConnectApi,
  topic,
  Schema.STRING_SCHEMA,
  line
)
...
```

So in the above code, if I add println(line) no strange chars are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you used the AvroConverter or the JsonConverter in your connector. Try using the StringConverter that ships with Kafka in your key.converter and value.converter in the worker for connect. That will encode the data as strings that shouldn't have this extra stuff in it.

Comment: You're right, it's avro! I don't specify the AvroConverter explicitly, but it seems to be the default converter. Also there is a kafka-avro-console-consumer Script in the bin directory in addition to the simple kafka-console-conumer script. By using that I get the correct message without strange bytes at the beginning. So the only thing left I have to figure out is how to specify the avro SerDer in my Kafka streams app. Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!